Getting Axios AggregateError [ETIMEDOUT]
I am encountering an Axios AggregateError [ETIMEDOUT] while making a POST request to the Meta Graph API (Facebook Graph API) with the following endpoint:
https://graph.facebook.com/v19.0/${id}/messages
I recently updated my Node.js application from version 16 to 22, and that's when the error started appearing. The specific error message I am receiving is:
connect ENETUNREACH 2a03:2880:f042:12:face:b00c:0:2:443 - Local (:::0)
Here is a Cloudwatch screenshot of the error logs.logs captured on cloudwatch
Since the address is IPv6, I enabled outbound traffic for IPv6 in my application. After doing this, I did not encounter any issues for the rest of the day, but the next day, the error reappeared.
I am not entirely sure what is causing this issue. Is this a problem with my Node.js configuration, or is there something else I need to configure to ensure consistent connectivity to the Meta Graph API?
Any guidance would be appreciated. Thank you!

Did you find any solution?

I encountered similar issue with google maps urls: I was trying unofficially extract coordinates from gmaps shortened links with nodejs and  occasionally saw this error.
It's not related to nodejs, but rather to network configuration. I ran the same docker image in different locations: same links can cause an error at my local machine, but work ok on a VPS.

@tomas No, I didn't find any solution for this yet.

@alexdao108 I tried deploying same application in other regions but this error was still occurring randomly. In the end, I have to degrade NodeJs version.
